# python: stateless function library design

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a library of various functions that will be often reused in the project. Each function is stateless (doesn't require parameters at creation, and doesn't have any memory). Some functions use others.

These functions would be passed around as arguments in the rest of the project.

Which of the following approaches is better?

1.Define all functions as global functions in a certain module:

```
def f1(x):
  # use x

def f2(x):
  # use x and f1
```

2.Define all functions as methods in classes, and arrange the classes in a hierarchy based on use:

```
class F1:
  def __call__(x):
    # use x

f1 = F1()

class F2(F1):
  def __call__(x):
    # use x and f1

f2 = F2()
```

The reason I even considered option 2 is that some of my functions have something in common. E.g., functions `f2`, `f3`, `f11` all start by calling `f1`. I was thinking I might want to do something like this:

```
class F1:
  def __call__(self, x):
     self.f1(x)
     self.calc(x)
  def f1(self, x):
     # do something
  # don't define calc here; F1 is abstract base class 

class F2(F1):
  def calc(self, x):
     # do something

class F3(F1):
  def calc(self, x):
     # do something
```

Comment: Where did you even get the idea to do 2?

Comment: @FrancisAvila: see my updated question to explain my thinking.

Comment: Did you mean to have `F2` and `F3` extend `F1`? That's not what the code says...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is a LOT simpler.  Option 2 is needlessly complex!!

Another suggestion that may make testing easier:

1.1. Define them all as methods of a single class in one module.  Use @staticmethod and @classmethod decorators as appropriate.  That can make them easier to substitute with mocks or override with alternate implementations by providing a new class or a subclass later.

spam.py:

```
class Spam(object):
  @staticmethod
  def f1(x):
    # use x

  @classmethod
  def f2(cls, x):
    # use x and cls.f1
```

This is still more complex so you may just want to stick with option 1 until you have a *need* for the above.

Comment: What you're proposing with `@classmethod` is similar to what I was thinking about. I didn't want to force everything to be `@classmethod`, since I was thinking one day I might want to add a state to a function; since I'm writing the classes anyway, why not leave the flexibility for that potential need?

Comment: There are ways to replace the function with a class or object if it becomes necessary to have state, without changing the API.

Comment: @kindall: ah that's true. I didn't think of this. It's quite easy right - just use `__call__`?

Comment: With a class, you can do it one of two ways: use `__call__` on the class and then immediately after the class definition, instantiate the object and assign it to the name you had previously used for the function. Then the instance is callable like a function. Or you can use a metaclass to override the `__call__` behavior of the class itself. State can also be maintained using an indefinite generator rather than a class, and this can be coupled with a callable function that just calls `next()` on the generator.

Comment: Here's some stuff that you might have fun looking at (updated): http://pastebin.com/TMVaqeFm

Comment: @kindall: this is cool. I didn't realize that a `class` can be used as a callable object. I'd imagine the instance approach is the best in most cases?

Comment: I personally like the class/metaclass one a lot because it's so self-contained, but it isn't in Python 3 anymore, since you can't defined the metaclass as an inner class in Python 3. I think the instance will be recognized by most Python programmers most readily.

Answer (score 3):

If you need several functions to execute some common code in the beginning and/or in the end, you can put the common code in a decorator, as [explained here](http://mrcoles.com/blog/3-decorator-examples-and-awesome-python/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're not storing data in your classes, which you wouldn't be if these are stateless functions, I can't see any point in using them. Python lets you define functions at module level precisely so that you don't have to use classes unless you really need the capabilities of a class.